# Spring 3.0.5 - java.awt.HeadlessException - com.trend.iwss.jscan

Tags: java, spring, applet

I am migrating an application from 2.5.6 version to 3.0.5. First at all, I had to add the `-Djava.awt.headless=true` parameter to the virtual machine and when I run any of my application I get this severals times in the log trace:

```
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [ar/com/test/spring/applicationContext.xml]
-->> returning Frame NULL
java.awt.HeadlessException
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(Graphic sEnvironment.java:159)
at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:407)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:402)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:367)
.....
```

How can I avoid this error in the trace?...Do I need to add `Djava.awt.headless=true` parameter to avoid this error??

Here is an small sample:

```
package ar.com.test.spring;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlAp plicationContext;

public class Test {
   private static final String[] LOCATIONS = {"ar/com/test/spring/applicationContext.xml"};

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(LOCATIONS);
   }
}
```

applicationContext.xml content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

</beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ar.com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>spring</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
<spring.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.0.2</version>
<configuration>
<source>1.6</source>
<target>1.6</target>
<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
<showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
<showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Full Trace:

Current policy properties:

```
mmc.sess_pe_act.block_unsigned: false
window.num_max: 5
jscan.sess_applet_act.sig_trusted: pass
file.destructive.state: disabled
jscan.sess_applet_act.block_all: false
window.num_limited: true
jscan.sess_applet_act.unsigned: instrument
mmc.sess_pe_act.action: validate
jscan.session.daemon_protocol: http
file.read.state: disabled
mmc.sess_pe_act.block_invalid: true
mmc.sess_pe_act.block_blacklisted: false
net.bind_enable: false
jscan.session.policyname: TU1DIERlZmF1bHQgUG9saWN5
mmc.sess_cab_act.block_unsigned: false
file.nondestructive.state: disabled
jscan.session.origin_uri: http://repo1.maven.org:80/maven2/org/springframework/spring-context/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
mmc.sess_cab_act.action: validate
net.connect_other: false
jscan.session.user_ipaddr: 172.16.4.200
jscan.sess_applet_act.sig_invalid: instrument
mmc.sess_cab_act.block_invalid: true
thread.thread_num_max: 8
jscan.sess_applet_act.sig_blacklisted: pass
net.connect_src: true
thread.thread_num_limited: true
jscan.sess_applet_act.stub_out_blocked_applet: true
mmc.sess_cab_act.block_blacklisted: true
mmc.sess_pe_act.enforce_for_com_objects_only: true
jscan.session.user_name: Q0hBQ09OTQ==
thread.threadgroup_create: false
file.write.state: disabled
```

---

```
03/05/2011 09:21:26 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@f81843: startup date [Tue May 03 09:21:26 GMT-03:00 2011]; root of context hierarchy
03/05/2011 09:21:28 org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [ar/com/test/spring/applicationContext.xml]
-->> returning Frame NULL
java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:159)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:407)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:402)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:367)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.BaseDialog.getActiveFrame(BaseDialog.java:75)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.AllowDialog.make(AllowDialog.java:32)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.showAllowDialog(PolicyRuntime.java:325)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.stopActionInner(PolicyRuntime.java:240)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.stopAction(PolicyRuntime.java:172)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.stopAction(PolicyRuntime.java:165)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.NetworkPolicyRuntime.checkURL(NetworkPolicyRuntime.java:284)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.NetworkPolicyRuntime._preFilter(NetworkPolicyRuntime.java:164)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.preFilter(PolicyRuntime.java:132)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.NetworkPolicyRuntime.preFilter(NetworkPolicyRuntime.java:108)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver.getSchemaMappings(PluggableSchemaResolver.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver.resolveEntity(PluggableSchemaResolver.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DelegatingEntityResolver.resolveEntity(DelegatingEntityResolver.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.ResourceEntityResolver.resolveEntity(ResourceEntityResolver.java:74)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.EntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(EntityResolverWrapper.java:107)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1100)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.resolveDocument(XMLSchemaLoader.java:595)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2403)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1753)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:685)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:626)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3088)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:914)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:508)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:225)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:283)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:126)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at ar.com.test.spring.Test.main(Test.java:9)
-->> returning Frame NULL
java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:159)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:407)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:402)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:367)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.BaseDialog.getActiveFrame(BaseDialog.java:75)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.AllowDialog.make(AllowDialog.java:32)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.showAllowDialog(PolicyRuntime.java:325)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.stopActionInner(PolicyRuntime.java:240)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.stopAction(PolicyRuntime.java:172)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.stopAction(PolicyRuntime.java:165)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.NetworkPolicyRuntime.checkURL(NetworkPolicyRuntime.java:284)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.NetworkPolicyRuntime._preFilter(NetworkPolicyRuntime.java:164)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.preFilter(PolicyRuntime.java:132)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.NetworkPolicyRuntime.preFilter(NetworkPolicyRuntime.java:108)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver.getSchemaMappings(PluggableSchemaResolver.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver.resolveEntity(PluggableSchemaResolver.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DelegatingEntityResolver.resolveEntity(DelegatingEntityResolver.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.ResourceEntityResolver.resolveEntity(ResourceEntityResolver.java:74)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.EntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(EntityResolverWrapper.java:107)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1100)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.resolveDocument(XMLSchemaLoader.java:595)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2403)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1753)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:685)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:626)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3088)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:914)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:508)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:225)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:283)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:126)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at ar.com.test.spring.Test.main(Test.java:9)
-->> returning Frame NULL
java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:159)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:407)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:402)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:367)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.BaseDialog.getActiveFrame(BaseDialog.java:75)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.AllowDialog.make(AllowDialog.java:32)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.showAllowDialog(PolicyRuntime.java:325)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.stopActionInner(PolicyRuntime.java:240)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.stopAction(PolicyRuntime.java:172)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.stopAction(PolicyRuntime.java:165)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.NetworkPolicyRuntime.checkURL(NetworkPolicyRuntime.java:284)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.NetworkPolicyRuntime._preFilter(NetworkPolicyRuntime.java:164)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.preFilter(PolicyRuntime.java:132)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.NetworkPolicyRuntime.preFilter(NetworkPolicyRuntime.java:108)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver.getSchemaMappings(PluggableSchemaResolver.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver.resolveEntity(PluggableSchemaResolver.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DelegatingEntityResolver.resolveEntity(DelegatingEntityResolver.java:85)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.ResourceEntityResolver.resolveEntity(ResourceEntityResolver.java:74)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.EntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(EntityResolverWrapper.java:107)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1100)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.resolveDocument(XMLSchemaLoader.java:595)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2403)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1753)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:685)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:626)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3088)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:914)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:508)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:225)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:283)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:126)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at ar.com.test.spring.Test.main(Test.java:9)
-->> returning Frame NULL
java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:159)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:407)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:402)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:367)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.BaseDialog.getActiveFrame(BaseDialog.java:75)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.AllowDialog.make(AllowDialog.java:32)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.showAllowDialog(PolicyRuntime.java:325)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.stopActionInner(PolicyRuntime.java:240)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.stopAction(PolicyRuntime.java:172)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.MiscPolicyRuntime._preFilter(MiscPolicyRuntime.java:185)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.preFilter(PolicyRuntime.java:132)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.MiscPolicyRuntime.preFilter(MiscPolicyRuntime.java:142)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:511)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:400)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at ar.com.test.spring.Test.main(Test.java:9)
03/05/2011 09:21:29 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@152c4d9: defining beans []; root of factory hierarchy
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense, there's no AWT stuff anywhere in your sample.  Is that stack all you have?  Did you cut it short?  If so, show us the whole trace.

Comment: Hello skaffman, first at all thank you very much for your reply, here is the full trace, please let me know if you need another information.

Comment: Hi! The issue was the AntiVirus Office scan of my office. Sometime it downloads the maven dependencies corrupt, so the solution you have to delete them and re-download them a few times and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Today I faced the similar problem. I want to share my research, maybe it will be helpful for somebody.

**The symptoms:**

When you use any java software you get pop-up "Applet alert" "Applet is attempting to..." BUT you know that you don't use any applets.

If you press the "Stop Applet" button on pop-up or suppress pop-up using `Djava.awt.headless=true` or other way you will see in the log an error like

```
java.awt.HeadlessException
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:159)
at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:407)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:402)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:367)
at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.BaseDialog.getActiveFrame(BaseDialog.java:75)
at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.AllowDialog.make(AllowDialog.java:32)
at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.showAllowDialog(PolicyRuntime.java:325)
at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.stopActionInner(PolicyRuntime.java:240)
at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.stopAction(PolicyRuntime.java:172)
at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.stopAction(PolicyRuntime.java:165)
at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.NetworkPolicyRuntime.checkURL(NetworkPolicyRuntime.java:284)
at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.NetworkPolicyRuntime._preFilter(NetworkPolicyRuntime.java:164)
at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.preFilter(PolicyRuntime.java:132)
at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.NetworkPolicyRuntime.preFilter(NetworkPolicyRuntime.java:108)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:108)
...
```

or

```
ActionServlet - Unable to initialize Struts ActionServlet due to an unexpected exception or error thrown, so marking the servlet as unavailable.  Most likely, this is due to an incorrect or missing library dependency. <com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.AppletTrapStopError: Applet disabled by IWSS Javascan site policy.>com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.AppletTrapStopError: Applet disabled by IWSS Javascan site policy.
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.stopApplet(PolicyRuntime.java:300)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.stopActionInner(PolicyRuntime.java:254)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.stopAction(PolicyRuntime.java:172)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.stopAction(PolicyRuntime.java:165)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.NetworkPolicyRuntime.checkURL(NetworkPolicyRuntime.java:284)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.NetworkPolicyRuntime._preFilter(NetworkPolicyRuntime.java:164)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.preFilter(PolicyRuntime.java:132)
    at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.NetworkPolicyRuntime.preFilter(NetworkPolicyRuntime.java:108)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.createInputSourceFromURL(Digester.java:1971)
    ...
```

You can see that pop-up is created by the code from `com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime` package.

**The reason:**

You are using jar that was downloaded from internet through Trend Micro InterScan Web Security Suite/Appliance proxy. This proxy make hooks in all jars that you download from internet, so that when they try to access files you see pop-up "Applet alert".

You may determine the affected jar by last stack-trace entrance before `com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime` package. (In my case it is `org.apache.commons.digester.Digester` from commons-digester.jar, in masch's case it is `org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils` from spring.jar)

**Solution:**

You have two options:

- You may download archived jar files. So they will not be affected by proxy.
- You may configure proxy not to modify downloading jar files.

[Problem description on Trend Micro web site](http://esupport.trendmicro.com/Pages/IWSx-3x-Some-files-and-folders-are-added-to-the-Jar-files-after-passin.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is the critical part:

```
at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.NetworkPolicyRuntime.preFilter(NetworkPolicyRuntime.java:108)
at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadAllProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:108)
```

You have some weird security software attached to your JVM, which is intercepting calls from Spring. It seems to be requiring that AWT is up and running, so that it can show a dialog box, which is moronic, and your `headless` config setting is making it fail.

Why did you add `Djava.awt.headless=true` to start with?  What happens without it?

Comment: `-Djava.awt.headless` is normally used to tell the code (e.g. if it  runs on a  server) not to try to use AWT, the server might not even have X or not even a VGA card installed.

Comment: @BertNase: yes, I realise that, but it shouldn't be required in the first place.

Comment: If I do not use it, I get severals pop up like these:

The applet is attemting to connect to jar:file:C:/spring/target/spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring.schemas
The applet is attemting to connect to jar:file:C:/spring/target/spring-conext-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring.schemas
The applet is attemting to connect to jar:file:C:/spring/target/spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring.schemas
The applet is attemting to invoke the java/lang/System.getProperties() operation

Each of them have three options: Allow, Disallow and Stop Applet.

Comment: @skaffman: depending on the execution environment it might be necessary, otherwise the JVM might crash less gracefully in a more internal part of the AWT code in case no graphics environment can be set up

Comment: @masch: so Is it the only way to avoid them? Is it "ok" those exceptions in the trace?

Comment: aaah - Applet.  - For applets you can request certain non-standard permissions, some require the applet to be signed -- see http://stackoverflow.com/q/608387/702599 Otherwise the JVM running the applet will always prompt the user for allowing the 'unsafe' operations.  Why do you use applets? If you really need them, access to client-side files is considered a harmful operation, accessing the necessary resources via the ClassLoader and bundling them into your applet jar is the easiest alternative. So your problem is connected to the general security restrictions for Applets...

Comment: @skaffman: Sorry, but I do not understand, I am not using applet in this sample. Do is it using Spring 3?

Answer (score 0):

`at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.showAllowDialog` does say it all, some of the policy checking code wantts to show a confirm dialog, either the "jscan" lib is misconfigured or it is only intended for interactive use va a Swing UI.
As it turned out in the discussion, the problem is caused by the code being run as an Java ppplet. The security restrictions for Applets cause the executing VM to interactively (via a SWING UI) ask the user for the permission of accessing local files. 
Local files and applets will hardly work anyway, so the best bet is that you need to bundle your resources (config files etc) into the applet jar and load them via the ClassLoader (e.g. `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/path/to/props.properties")`)

Comment: The only local file loaded by the sample is applicationContext.xml and it is loaded from the classpath of the jar application "ar/com/test/spring/applicationContext.xml". Is it correct?