# maven - getting a popup asking for permission while building

Tags: java, maven, build

I have freshly installed maven and while building hello world, maven keeps asking me for permission with messages like - "The applet is attempting to access the "exists" state attributes of file ..."

Seems like it isn't a very common problem. Is there any way to grant these permissions to maven?

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building tms-server 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) @ tms-server ---
Current policy properties:
    mmc.sess_pe_act.block_unsigned: false
    window.num_max: 5
    jscan.sess_applet_act.sig_trusted: pass
    jscan.sess_applet_act.block_all: false
    file.destructive.state: disabled
    window.num_limited: true
    jscan.sess_applet_act.unsigned: instrument
    mmc.sess_pe_act.action: validate
    jscan.session.daemon_protocol: http
    file.read.state: disabled
    mmc.sess_pe_act.block_invalid: true
    mmc.sess_pe_act.block_blacklisted: false
    jscan.session.policyname: QXBwbGV0L0FjdGl2ZVggU2VjdXJpdHkgR2xvYmFsIFBvbGljeSA=
    net.bind_enable: false
    mmc.sess_cab_act.block_unsigned: false
    file.nondestructive.state: disabled
    jscan.session.origin_uri: 
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/1.0-beta-2/maven-filtering-1.0-beta-2.jar
    mmc.sess_cab_act.action: validate
    net.connect_other: false
    jscan.session.user_ipaddr: 10.109.50.50
    jscan.sess_applet_act.sig_invalid: block
    thread.thread_num_max: 8
    mmc.sess_cab_act.block_invalid: true
    jscan.sess_applet_act.sig_blacklisted: block
    net.connect_src: true
    thread.thread_num_limited: true
    jscan.sess_applet_act.stub_out_blocked_applet: true
    mmc.sess_cab_act.block_blacklisted: true
    jscan.session.user_name: MTAuMTA5LjUwLjUw
    thread.threadgroup_create: false
    file.write.state: disabled
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
-->> returning Frame NULL
BaseDialog: owner frame is a java.awt.Frame
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.925s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Mar 25 12:55:59 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/74M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources (default-resources) on project tms-server: 
Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.3:resources failed: The Applet is not allowed to access 
the "exists" state attributes of file /root/tms-server/src/main/resources by IWSVA Javascan site policy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Update: Here is my pom.xml, it is straight from apache's getting started guide.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>app</groupId>
  <artifactId>tms-server</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>tms-server</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Please post you `pom.xml` file?

Comment: How did you build this? Which command?

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran mvn package

Comment: Which platform you're executing? Windows, Mac or Linux? It looks like about the permission to access some resources.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It says,

> The Applet is not allowed to access  the "exists" state attributes of
>   file /root/tms-server/src/main/resources by IWSVA Javascan site
>   policy.

You are using jar that was downloaded from internet through Trend Micro InterScan Web Security Suite/Appliance proxy. This proxy make hooks in all jars that you download from Internet, so that when they try to access files you see pop-up "Applet alert".

Solution:

You have two options:

1. You may download archived jar files. So they will not be affected by
   proxy.
2. You may configure proxy not to modify downloading jar files.

There is another user got this issue and solved, I got this answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862560/java-awt-headlessexception-in-spring-3-0-5/8038090#8038090)

Comment: Thanks, the problem was indeed caused by the Trend Micro firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You must to clean the classpath jars from TrendMicro trash, I use this ant's script:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="cleanTrendMicro" default="doit" basedir=".">
    <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
      <classpath>
        <pathelement location="/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
      </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <!-- global properties -->
    <property environment="env" />
    <property name="home.dir" location="." />
    <property name="tmp.dir" value="${home.dir}/tmp" />

    <path id="plugin.path" path="${home.dir}"   >
        <fileset dir="plugins" casesensitive="yes">
            <include name="**/*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="doit">
        <echo message="Created by DanTechologies"/>
        <foreach target="retar" param="theFile">
            <path refid="plugin.path" />
        </foreach>
    </target>

    <target name="retar">
        <if>
            <available file="${theFile}" type="dir" />
            <then>
                <echo message="Directory ${theFile}" />
            </then>
            <else>
                <echo message="Procesing file: ${theFile}"/>
                <mkdir dir="${tmp.dir}" />
                <unzip src="${theFile}" dest="${tmp.dir}"/>
                <jar destfile="${theFile}" basedir="${tmp.dir}" excludes="**/com/trend/**" />
                <delete quiet="true" dir="${tmp.dir}" />
            </else>
        </if>
    </target>
</project>
```