# Spring: Apache POI Excel file download "Current policy properties" error in build log

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-poi

I have a very simple Controller method that downloads an excel file using Apache POI library which is generated in a Service class like so:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

// Excel sheet populated and added to workbook

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("file.xlsx"));
workbook.write(out);

out.close();
```

And the following Controller method triggers a download.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/fileDownload")
public String downloadMatchingExcel(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{

    response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename = file.xlsx");
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));

    FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("file.xlsx"));

    IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());

    response.flushBuffer();
    response.getOutputStream().close();

}
```

The file is generated and downloaded without any problems. But I get the following error in the build log.

```
[ERROR] Current policy properties:
[ERROR]     mmc.sess_pe_act.block_unsigned: false
[ERROR]     window.num_max: 5
[ERROR]     jscan.sess_applet_act.sig_trusted: pass
[ERROR]     jscan.sess_applet_act.block_all: false
[ERROR]     file.destructive.state: disabled
[ERROR]     window.num_limited: true
[ERROR]     jscan.sess_applet_act.unsigned: instrument
[ERROR]     mmc.sess_pe_act.action: validate
[ERROR]     jscan.session.daemon_protocol: http
[ERROR]     file.read.state: disabled
[ERROR]     mmc.sess_pe_act.block_invalid: true
[ERROR]     mmc.sess_pe_act.block_blacklisted: false
[ERROR]     jscan.session.policyname: QXBwbGV0L0FjdGl2ZVggU2VjdXJpdHkgR2xvYmFsIFBvbGljeSA=
[ERROR]     net.bind_enable: false
[ERROR]     mmc.sess_cab_act.block_unsigned: false
[ERROR]     file.nondestructive.state: disabled
[ERROR]     jscan.session.origin_uri: http://repo.spring.io/libs-release/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml/3.11/poi-ooxml-3.11.jar
[ERROR]     mmc.sess_cab_act.action: validate
[ERROR]     net.connect_other: false
[ERROR]     jscan.session.user_ipaddr: 172.24.8.56
[ERROR]     jscan.sess_applet_act.sig_invalid: block
[ERROR]     thread.thread_num_max: 8
[ERROR]     mmc.sess_cab_act.block_invalid: true
[ERROR]     jscan.sess_applet_act.sig_blacklisted: block
[ERROR]     net.connect_src: true
[ERROR]     thread.thread_num_limited: true
[ERROR]     jscan.sess_applet_act.stub_out_blocked_applet: true
[ERROR]     mmc.sess_cab_act.block_blacklisted: true
[ERROR]     jscan.session.user_name: MTcyLjI0LjguNTY=
[ERROR]     thread.threadgroup_create: false
[ERROR]     file.write.state: disabled
```

What does it mean? And is it something to worry about?

Answer (score 0):

There is lots of relative question in here, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667357/java-policy-error-applet-alert) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609836/maven-getting-a-popup-asking-for-permission-while-building)
It seems it cause by some firewall/proxy/antivirus modify the jar you download.