# 'new HiveContext' is wanting an X11 display? com.trend.iwss.jscan?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Spark 1.6.2 (YARN master)

Package name: com.example.spark.Main

---

Basic SparkSQL code

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
conf.setAppName("SparkSQL w/ Hive")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
import hiveContext.implicits._

// val rdd = <some RDD making>
val df = rdd.toDF()
df.write.saveAsTable("example")
```

And stacktrace...

```
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
         at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
         at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
         at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
         at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
         at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.BaseDialog.getActiveFrame(BaseDialog.java:75)
         at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.AllowDialog.make(AllowDialog.java:32)
         at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.showAllowDialog(PolicyRuntime.java:325)
         at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.stopActionInner(PolicyRuntime.java:240)
         at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.stopAction(PolicyRuntime.java:172)
         at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.stopAction(PolicyRuntime.java:165)
         at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.NetworkPolicyRuntime.checkURL(NetworkPolicyRuntime.java:284)
         at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.NetworkPolicyRuntime._preFilter(NetworkPolicyRuntime.java:164)
         at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.PolicyRuntime.preFilter(PolicyRuntime.java:132)
         at com.trend.iwss.jscan.runtime.NetworkPolicyRuntime.preFilter(NetworkPolicyRuntime.java:108)
         at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$5.run(LogFactory.java:1346)
         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
         at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getProperties(LogFactory.java:1376)
         at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getConfigurationFile(LogFactory.java:1412)
         at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getFactory(LogFactory.java:455)
         at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:657)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure.<clinit>(HadoopShimsSecure.java:60)
         at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.createShim(ShimLoader.java:146)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.loadShims(ShimLoader.java:141)
         at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getHadoopShims(ShimLoader.java:100)
         at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.overrideHadoopShims(ClientWrapper.scala:116)
         at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.<init>(ClientWrapper.scala:69)
         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
         at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:249)
         at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.metadataHive$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:345)
         at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.metadataHive(HiveContext.scala:255)
         at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.setConf(HiveContext.scala:459)
         at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.defaultOverrides(HiveContext.scala:233)
         at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:236)
         at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:101)
         at com.example.spark.Main1$.main(Main.scala:52)
         at com.example.spark.Main.main(Main.scala)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
 ivysettings.xml file not found in HIVE_HOME or HIVE_CONF_DIR,/etc/hive/2.5.3.0-37/0/ivysettings.xml will be used
```

---

This same code was working a week ago on a fresh HDP cluster, and it works fine in the sandbox... the only thing I remember doing was trying to change around the JAVA_HOME variable, but I am fairly sure I undid those changes.
I'm at a loss - not sure how to start tracking down the issue.

The cluster is headless, so of-course it has no X11 display, but what piece of `new HiveContext` even needs to pop-up any `JFrame`?

Based on the logs, I'd say it's a Java configuration issue I messed up and something within `org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure.<clinit>(HadoopShimsSecure.java:60)` got triggered, therefore a Java security dialog is appearing, but I don't know.

Can't do X11 forwarding, and tried to do `export SPARK_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"` before a `spark-submit`, and that didn't help.

Tried these, but again, can't forward and don't have a display

- [Getting a HeadlessException: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218870/getting-a-headlessexception-no-x11-display-variable-was-set)
- ["No X11 DISPLAY variable" - what does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662421/no-x11-display-variable-what-does-it-mean)

The error seems to be reproducible on two of the Spark clients.
Only on one machine did I try changing `JAVA_HOME`.

Did an Ambari Hive service-check. Didn't fix it.
Can connect fine to Hive database via Hive/Beeline CLI

Comment: `com.trend.iwss.jscan` looks suspiciously like a Trend Micro antivirus probe inserted into your JVM, believing that you are running malicious code, and trying to pop up an alert message box...

Comment: I was thinking a similar thing... Which lead me here... https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/4cf9094f-1bc1-49d7-b0bf-85206228053c%40r33g2000yqn.googlegroups.com#4cf9094f-1bc1-49d7-b0bf-85206228053c@r33g2000yqn.googlegroups.com The Maven packages are being downloaded through a company firewall... Not sure what I can do about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the Spark code is concerned, this seemed to mitigate the error.

```
val conf = SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions" , "-Djava.awt.headless=true")
```

---

**Original answer**

Found this post. [Spring 3.0.5 - java.awt.HeadlessException - com.trend.iwss.jscan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862560/java-awt-headlessexception-in-spring-3-0-5)

Basically, Trend Micro is inserting some `com.trend.iwss.jscan` package into the JAR files that are downloaded via Maven through a company firewall , and I have no control over that.

(link not working) http://esupport.trendmicro.com/Pages/IWSx-3x-Some-files-and-folders-are-added-to-the-Jar-files-after-passin.aspx

Wayback Machine to the rescue...

If anyone else has input, I would also like to hear it.

> **Problem**:
>   When downloading some .JAR files via IWSA, a directory filled with .class file, which is not related to what is being downloaded, is added to the jar file (`com\trend\iwss\jscan\runtime\`).
>
> **Solution**:
>   This happens because if a JAR file is originally unsigned, IWSA will insert some code into the applet to monitor and restrict potential harmful actions.
>
> For IWSS/IWSA, every "get" request is the same so it will not know if you are trying to download an archive or an applet, which will be executed by your browser.
>
> This code is added for security reason to monitor the behavior of the "possible" applet to be sure that it does not do any harm to the machine and its environment.
>
> To prevent this issue, please follow these steps:
>
> 1. Log on to the IWSS web console.
> 2. Go to HTTP > Applets and ActiveX > Policies > Java Applet Security Rules.
> 3. Under Java Applet Security, change the value of "No signature" to either "Pass" or "Block", depending on what you want to do with the unsigned .JAR files.
> 4. Click Save.

Comment: After all, an unsigned JAR is just a ZIP archive. If an antivirus can add stuff, then you can delete that stuff, i.e. `zip -d tainted-with-stuff.jar '/com/trend/*'`

Comment: Sure, but the fact that I have spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-core... you get the picture... I'd rather not scrape out trend from all of them if I can't avoid it

Comment: Are you afraid that Trend IWSS is an endangered species?! I'm in favor of eradication i.e. `for J in *.jar; do if [[ $(unzip -l $J | grep -c com/trend/) -ne 0 ]]; then   zip -d $J 'com/trend/*'; fi; done` »:-0

Comment: Ha. I mean, yes, that will work in theory. My point was that I don't want to do it for every *new JAR file* that gets downloaded.